# Trouble returning a lifetime bound reference from an iterator

Tags: rust

I am writing an iterator to produce coordinate points for a grid (`0 <= x < width`, `0 <= y < height`) and would like to use a single mutable `Point` for the iterated value (so as to avoid churning millions of structs). I know it's a bit of "premature optimization", but I want to do it to make sure I understand enough about reference lifetimes for other things.

I figure this should be safe since the code receiving the value will get the reference with the lifetime attached, so can't arbitrarily pass the pointer outside of anywhere.

Since the iterator must be borrowed mutably in order to call `next()`, I figure the use of the result should be limited such that nobody outside can see it be modified (the intent is to only use this in a fluent iterator chain, rather than calling 'next()' manually, but I appreciate the code must be safe either way.

My code is:

```rust
#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct Piter<'a> {
    grid: &'a AGrid,
    cur: Point<usize>,  // A reference to this is returned from the iterator every time.
    nxt: Point<usize>,
}

impl<'a> Iterator for Piter<'a> {
    type Item = &'a Point<usize>;

    fn next(&'a mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        self.cur = self.nxt;
        if self.nxt.y < self.grid.height() {
            self.nxt.x += 1;
            if self.nxt.x == self.grid.width() {
                self.nxt.x = 0;
                self.nxt.y += 1;
            }
            return Some(&self.cur);
        }
        None
    }
}
```

The error message is:

```
error[E0308]: method not compatible with trait
  --> src\agrid.rs:85:5
   |
85 |     fn next(&'a mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ lifetime mismatch
   |
   = note: expected signature `fn(&mut Piter<'a>) -> Option<_>`
              found signature `fn(&'a mut Piter<'a>) -> Option<_>`
note: the anonymous lifetime as defined here...
  --> src\agrid.rs:85:5
   |
85 |     fn next(&'a mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
note: ...does not necessarily outlive the lifetime `'a` as defined here
  --> src\agrid.rs:82:6
   |
82 | impl<'a> Iterator for Piter<'a> {
   |      ^^
```

I'm not actually sure what the "anonymous lifetime" being referred to is for:

```
note: the anonymous lifetime as defined here...
  --> src\agrid.rs:85:5
   |
85 |     fn next(&'a mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

or how to make it explicit (if that's possible).

I've tried various ways to fiddle the lifetimes, but to no avail.

My main question is:
Is the idea of returning the same mutable reference for iteration acceptable (I don't care about optimization discussion, only if it's a reasonable pattern) ?

And secondarily, if it is reasonable, how can I adjust lifetimes to make this work?

Comment: Possibly, I'm having a look at the "streaming-iterator" crate and while it's promising, it does have the issue of assuming the iterator starts at "the item before the first one" which is a problem when using `usize` and wanting to start at zero. The alternative reading is that it's not really possible/a good idea, but I'd hope that's not the case.

Comment: @David If that's the problem you're having, perhaps `Option<usize>` would be an acceptable solution?

Comment: Also, I'm a bit curious about your precise use case. You mention "churning millions of structs", but your `Point` struct appears to only hold `x` and `y` and therefore I'd assume it to be non-allocating. I don't mean to sound patronizing, but are you aware that such structs are really cheap to allocate in Rust because they incur no allocator pressure (unlike in languages like Java or Python), and can be treated as just two numbers by the compiler? Perhaps this optimization is premature.

Comment: Not really since it would be `Option<Point<usize>>` and that mean I'd need to replace the `Point` value each time, which obviates the idea of referencing a single mutable item.

`StreamingIterator` almost worked, but I can't use it with standard fluent methods like `exactly_one()`. I think I'll give up on it for now.

Comment: Well that's what I'm proposing, that you return `Option<Point<usize>>`, and not attempt to reference a single mutable item. Did you measure that the simple solution is the bottleneck (in release mode)?

Comment: I am very aware that this isn't going to be a big issue (or perhaps any issue) in this case, but I'm exploring Rust idioms and wondered if this idea would ever be a reasonable thing to do. As I stated: "I want to do it to make sure I understand enough about reference lifetimes for other things".

Comment: It's very reasonable if the item produced by the iterator allocates or is otherwise expensive to construct (compared to updating it). But it comes with **serious** limitations and complications, so it's almost certainly not something you want to do unless you really need it.

Comment: @David, iterators like the one you describe here can't be expressed using the stdlib's Iterator trait. There have been many questions asked about it, as people invariably try it and bang their head against the wall - it can't be done. What the other comments here point out is that you are in the fortunate situation that `Point` is (at least afaics) extremely cheap to copy, so it's possible to return owned versions of it, avoid the problem altogether, at let copy-propagation-optimization do its job in rescuing the day.

Comment: Fair enough. I'll bare this in mind when designing iterators in future (i.e. aim to only iterate over small, copyable instances). Thanks for the quick responses.